# AWS Lambda function error when called on postman or localhost Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created a `nodejs lambda` function. When I started, it worked properly but when I update it, I am getting this issue.

When I test it on `aws` Test section in cloudwatch, I get proper response logs, but when I try on `postman` or `localhost`, I am getting this error.

The `Error` is:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
{
    errno: -3008,
    code: 'ENOTFOUND',
    syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
    hostname: 'somekey_cannot_display.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com'
}
```

How can I fix this as I am not getting proper response from other sources.

I tried adding new permission and adding vpc both public and private.

Comment: Bind with domain/custom domain using route53. because while you upload/update lamda function its change somekey_cannot_display.